# HighChart stacked column - refresh dynamically categories and series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Let's say I have a chart with stacked columns.
On the X axis, let's say I have cities.
On the Y axis, the stacked columns are made of 5 series.

When I first load the chart, I have for example 20 cities, all displaying the stacked columns based on the 5 series.

Then, I simulate a modification of the data on the back-end side, so that there will be only 2 cities displayed.
When I try to refresh programmatically the chart, with the method char.update({}) and options "redraw", "oneToOne" set to true, what I get is the following:

. The chart is still displaying the columns for the initial set of 20 cities, and not only for the 2 cities (as I would expect)

. On the X axis, I can see the names of the 2 cities (as I would expect), but now there are 18 numbers (1,2,3,4...) displayed as the place of the previously displayed city names.

What is the method to refresh xAxis.categories and series at the same time, and have the chart refreshed / redrawn?
My HighChart library is old now, it is a V5 from 2017. Is it the issue? Is there a way I can access the API for the old version?

Thanks!
Vinc.

Comment: Could you reproduce your described case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay. Meanwhile I found this issue, which was only on my side: I was passing an object instead of an array.